# gcutil --filter arguments error

Tags: filter, google-cloud-platform, gcutil

Encountered a problem trying to run `gcutil listinstances --filter="name eq foo"` (for example...)

I get the following error: 
*RuntimeError: CommandError: Unknown argument: "eq", "foo"*

This follows the examples found in the [official usage tips](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gcutil/tips).

Seems as if 'eq' and 'foo' get parsed as independent arguments for gcutil...

Does this result from a bug in gcutil or the way I use it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like an installation issue. Did you try reinstalling Google Cloud SDK?